# Ignite get column map types in Cassandra

Tags: ignite

Ignite-Cassandra module doesn't support Cassandra complex types like 
Map type. Only BLOB and simple types which could be directly mapped 
to appropriate java types are supported. 
What else to get Map type from Cassandra use Ignite?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JavaDoc for the [PersistenceStrategy](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/cassandra/persistence/PersistenceStrategy.html) enum.

There are three possible values: BLOB, POJO and PRIMITIVE. [POJO](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/cassandra/persistence/PersistenceStrategy.html#POJO) strategy can be used to store maps of primitive types.

You can use this strategy in your persistence settings. Example: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/examples#section-example-4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Denis,

But I want to persistence Map Type of java to Map Type Cassandra. Could be used only for POJO objects following Java Beans convention and having their fields of **simple java type** which could be directly mapped to corresponding Cassandra types. No complex type: map, list.